# uploading php files into my root folder and sending spam

Tags: php, spam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My server’s been hacked EMERGENCY](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency)

i do not understand how but someone is uploading a php file into the public_html directory of my CentOS 6 server like statisticsuQPo.php

this php file gives me "linux10+cfcd208495d565ef66e7dff9f98764da"

and it is sending spam mail's without end.

i have remove the file maybe 10 times but i do got it back every day.

how can i solve this problem? is there anything wrong with my apache configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Your 'problem' is almost certainly a buggy web-application combined with bad security settings.  Since your system was compromised you should almost certainly [nuke it from orbit and rebuild it](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency).

- Take it offline
- determine the root cause
- fix the problem
- actually harden your setup, so even if that app gets compromised again, it can't actually be used to install executable content in a location where it is possible for the code to be executed.

Simply deleting the files that are being created just addressing the symptoms.  You are not fixing the problem.